# LinearProgressIndicator Color

Tags: flutter

If I create a widget using this code:

```
child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
      new Expanded(
        child: LinearProgressIndicator(value: _animation.value, valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white)),
      ),
    ]),
```

How do I later access the setters to modify e.g. LinearProgressIndicator value or valueColor?

Comment: So, did you check the answer, find what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `setState` for changing

```
child: LinearProgressIndicator(value: _animation.value, valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(colorValue))
```

and for changing:

```
setState((){
    colorValue = /* new color */
});
```

Actually - there can be another solutions, e.g. create custom widget for show progress, use FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder. SetState - it's just easiest way to change something